# Database design for coupon usuage restriction

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, database-design

While working on implementing voucher feature for an eCommerce application, I need to implement Voucher usage restriction, some of restriction I am planning to have

1. Products
2. Exclude products
3. Product categories
4. Exclude categories
5. Email /Customer restrictions

Currently We are supporting following 2 type of Vouchers with an option to create Custom voucher type and all those Vouchers types are being maintained in a single table with help of discriminator (Hibernate use).

1. Serial Vouchers
2. Promotion Vouchers.

these are only few which I am targeting at initial stage.My main confusion is about database design and restriction of these `voucher usage` with `Voucher`.I am not able to decide which is best way to Map these restrictions in database.

Should I go for a single table for all these restriction and have a relation with `Voucher` table or is it good to group all similar type of restriction in a single table and have their relation with Voucher table.

As an additional information , we are using hibernate to map our entities with the DB table.

Comment: Is it feasible to have valid-products and valid-categories instead of

Comment: whther you use Hibernate or not is irrelevant to the correct deisgn of teh database or at least it should be. What is relevant is how is the data going to be used after it is entered and will differnt types of exclusions have different data needs as far as the is data stored? You also need to look at whether one table will become a hot spot in the database. This will depend to some extent on the amount of data and the amount of querying you expect see on that data.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a very wide-open and freeform requirement. Some questions:

How complex will the business rules you are attempting to model be? If you’re allowing (business) users to define their own vouchers, odds are good they’ll come up with some pretty byzantine rules and combinations. If you have to support **anything** they come up with, you will have problems.

What will the database be tasked to do with this data? Store the “voucher definition”, sure, but then what? Run tallies or reports on them? Analyze how many are used, by who/when/how/for what? Or just list out what was used/generated over the past year?

What kind of data volumes are you going to have? One entry per voucher definition, or per voucher printed/issued? (If the latter, can you use one entry per voucher, with a count of how many issued?) Are we talking dozens, hundreds, or millions of vouchers?

If it’s totally free-form, if they just want a listing without serious analysis, if the overall volume is small, consider using blob fields rather than minutiae-oriented columns. Something like a big text field and a data-entry box wherein the user will “Enter any other criteria defining the voucher”. (You might even do this using XML.) Ugly, you can’t readily analyze the data, but if the goals are too great or diffuse and you're not going to *use* all that detailed data, it might be necessary.

A final note: a voucher that is good for only selected products cannot be used on products that are added after the voucher is created. A voucher that is good for all *but* selected products *can* be used for subsequently created products. This logic may apply to any voucher-limiting criteria. Both methodologies have merit, make sure the users are clear on what they’re doing.

Comment: Yes it strikes me that the reason it is hard to define the struture is that the actual business requirements are poorly thought out and not nearly detailed enough to determine what is best to do. The OP appears to be approaching this from the standpoint of what the data entry will be and not from the standpoint of how the data will be used. In the case of something like vouchers espcially, how it will work to use the vouchers is key information that is missing.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what your your are doing, you will have a problem with only one table for all restrictions, because it means 1 row per `Voucher` and multiple values in your different restrictions columns.

It will be harder for you to UPDATE, extract and cast restrictions values.

In my opinion, you should have one table for each restrictions type and map them with `Voucher` table. However It will be easier for you to add new restrictions.

Comment: You mean that for each new restriction, I should have one table? but that means too much normalization.

Comment: Use rules on your tables to avoid duplicate insertion. The thing with multiple tables is that you will be able to add/remove products, categories, customers from you voucher without touching others values

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi, this is not anywhere close to too much normalization.

Answer (score 3):

As a suggestion:
Isn't it more rational to have `valid-products` and `valid-categories` instead of `Exclude-products` and `Exclude-categories`? 
Having a `Customer-Creditgroup` table will lead us to have `valid-customer-group` table.

BTW in the current design we can have a voucher definition table, I will call it `voucher-type` table.
[image]
About the restrictions:
In RDBMS level you can state only two types of table constraints decoratively:

- uniquely identifying attributes (keys)
- Subsets requirements referencing back to the same or other table
  (foreign key)

Implementing all other types of table constraints (like a multi-tuple constraints or transition constraints) requires you to develop procedural data integrity code.
When a voucher is going to sold to a specific customer for a specific product we will need to check validity of excluded elements, that could be done by triggers in data base level or business logic of your application.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally go with your second proposal... grouping all similar types of restrictions in a single table, which refers the Voucher table.

I'll add to that, that you can handle includes and excludes on the same table.

So the structure I'd use is some along the lines of:

```
Voucher                           (id, type, etc...)
VoucherProductRestriction         (id,voucher_id,product_id,include)
VoucherProductCategoryRestriction (id,voucher_id,product_category_id,include)
VoucherCustomerRestriction        (id,voucher_id,customer_id)
VoucherEmailRestriction           (id,voucher_id,email)
```

...where the include column could be a boolean that is true in case you want to restrict the voucher to that product or category, or false if you want to restrict it to any product or category other than those specificied.

If I understand your context correctly, it makes no sense to have both include and exclude restrictions on the same voucher (although it could make sense to have more than one of the same type). You can probably handle and check this better if you use a single table for both types of restrictions.